# OpenGL Unhandled exception in nvoglv32.dll glTexSubImage

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a very random crash that happens, 1 in 10 or so times I'll get a crash in `nvoglv32.dll`. It doesn't always happen in the exact same place, but it does happen within 10 or so lines from the same place.

I added the ability to update textures using `glTexSubImage2D()`, and now I have these intermittent crashes.

```
  void UpdateTexture(const GLuint textureID, const CaffApp::Dev::Format format, const CaffApp::Dev::TextureD dimention, const uint32_t offsetX, const uint32_t offsetY, const uint32_t width, const uint32_t height, void *data)
  {
    using namespace CaffApp::Dev;

    const auto externalFormat = format == Format::DEV ? GL_RGBA32F : GL_RGBA ;
    const auto internalFormat = GL_RGBA;
    const auto formatType     = format == Format::R8G8B8 ? GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE : GL_FLOAT;
    const auto glDimention    = GetDimentionTarget(dimention);

    assert(CaffMath::IsPOW2(texWidth));
    assert(CaffMath::IsPOW2(texHeight));

    glBindTexture(glDimention, textureID);

    switch(glDimention)
    {
      case(GL_TEXTURE_1D):
      {
        glTexSubImage1D(GL_TEXTURE_1D, offsetX, 0, texWidth, internalFormat, formatType, data);
        break;
      }
      case(GL_TEXTURE_2D):
      {
        glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, offsetX, offsetY, texWidth, texHeight, internalFormat, formatType, data);
        break;
      }
    };

    glBindTexture(glDimention, 0);
    GL_ERROR("Updating texture.")
  }

void Texture::updateSubset(const std::vector<float> &data, const uint32_t offsetX, const uint32_t offsetY)
{
  assert(m_textureID);

  uint32_t sizeX = m_width;
  uint32_t sizeY = m_height;

  if(sizeX == 0 || sizeY == 0)
  {
    SetTextureDimentionFromDataSize(m_dimention, data.size(), sizeX, sizeY);
  }

  UpdateTexture(m_textureID, m_format, m_dimention, offsetX, offsetY, sizeX, sizeY, (void*)data.data());

  GL_ERROR("Updating texture.")
}
```

If the crash happens it happens only at the first time glTexSubImage... is called. Otherwise its fine.

I did see something about vertex attributes not being set right, but I can't really see anything wrong there and that's code that hasn't been changed in 2 years or so, so thinking its around here instead.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably access out-of-bounds whatever `data` points to. This can happen if the alignment and strides are not properly set. It can also happen if data is allocated to short; it doesn't have to crash right when the first thing writes out-of-bounds, it can taint the address space and trigger the crash somewhere else.

Comment: Yep, I had forgotten to reserve enough space for the components in the array that was initially used to create the texture. `Width * Height * Components`